# Creating a tree using fork() with a number of children differs in value and changes each time

Tags: c, linux, fork

I try to create a process tree according to the values that are in my array.
So that for each process its number of children will be the number found in this cell in the array.
So I kept a number that keeps **how many children** I have so far and the **process which is running now**.

The thing is that in order for the processes to communicate with each other, I kept these values in the addresses in memory(pointers), but still things are not synchronized there.

I attach a pic of how it should be for array {2,3,1,0,0,0}:

[image]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv){
    int current_id=0;// id of the process running now
    int son_counter=0; // id for son
    
    int * p_current_id=&current_id;  
    int * p_son_counter=&son_counter;
    
    int my_num=0;//process num
    int arr[6]={2,1,2,1,0,0};
    
    for(int i=0;i<arr[*p_current_id];i++)
    {
        pid_t iam=fork();
        
        if(iam==0)//son
        {
            ++(*p_son_counter);
            printf("p_son_counter: %d\n", *p_son_counter);
            my_num=(*p_son_counter);//++ for the num of son
            //printf("p_son_counter: %d\n", *p_son_counter);
            while(*p_current_id<my_num)
            {
                sleep(1);
            }
            printf("Im process %d - %d and ready to start!\n", my_num, getpid());
            i=0;
        }
        else if(iam!=0)//father
        {
            printf("im the father %d - %d & i created process %d\n", my_num, getpid(), iam);
        }
    
    }
    printf("p_current_id: %d\n", *p_current_id);
    (*p_current_id)++;
    printf("p_current_id: %d\n", *p_current_id);
    printf("process %d - %d finished his job!",my_num, getpid()); 
    while(wait(NULL)>0);
    //printf("Process id %d, parent process id %d, my num : %d \n", getpid(), getppid(), my_id);

return 0;
}
```

And from some reason this is my output...

```
im the father 0 - 8186 & i created process 8187
im the father 0 - 8186 & i created process 8188
p_current_id:0
p_current_id:1
p_son_counter:1
p_son_counter:1
```

Comment: The right terms are "child" and "parent".

Comment: Variable changes in a child process are not reflected in the parent process or vice versa. You can not use variables in normal memory to communicate between the processes.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you use any interprocess communication mechanism of any kind. There would be chaos if one process modifying a variable changes its value in another process. No code would work -- even `i = i + 1` could fail if executed by two processes at the same time.

There is no semantic difference between accessing a variable directly by its identifier and accessing it indirectly through a pointer. Just using a pointer doesn't suddenly invoke some magic form of synchronization to make it safe to modify a variable in one process while another one might be in the process of accessing it.

If you want to share information between processes, you have to use some mechanism that provides synchronization and safety. You can use files, sockets, pipes, shared memory (with some kind of lock or exclusivity mechanism to avoid data races), or whatever else is available.

But you have to precisely specify what will be shared and what won't.

(Technically, you do use `wait`, which is a form of inter-process communication and synchronization.)

Comment: I understand.. Thank you! I'll try to work with files